# Raspberry Pi 3 access point stops working

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie, access-point

I set up a Raspberry Pi 3 as an access point following the [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) for connect a smartphone on tornado websocket on python
It works but frequently the AP stops working and I have to restart hostapd and dnsmasq.
When it stops, hostapd and dnsmasq are still running in task manager and if I run ifconfig, the line:
`inet addr:192.168.7.1  Bcast:192.168.7.255  Mask:255.255.255.0`
is missing and instead of:
`UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1`
there is:
`UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1`

I need the AP keep working continuously so:
1 ) how do I start the AP at boot?
2 ) how can I debug this interruption?
3 ) how can I restart the AP in case of problems?

**UPDATE 1**
in file /var/log/syslog there aren't entries today

**UPDATE 2**
sudo dmesg result after **apt update && apt dist-upgrade** (I had to remove the previous result because of characters limit):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dmesg 
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.9.35-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fd034] revision 4 (ARMv7), cr=10c5383d
[    0.000000] CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt:Machine model: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 8 MiB at 0x3a800000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 241664
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat 80c6ee40, node_mem_map b9faa000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 2124 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 241664 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 14 pages/cpu @b9f64000 s25600 r8192 d23552 u57344
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s25600 r8192 d23552 u57344 alloc=14*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 239540
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=0 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1280 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=1024 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 936296K/966656K available (7168K kernel code, 484K rwdata, 2012K rodata, 1024K init, 778K bss, 22168K reserved, 8192K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
    vmalloc : 0xbb800000 - 0xff800000   (1088 MB)
    lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0xbb000000   ( 944 MB)
    modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x80000000   (  16 MB)
      .text : 0x80008000 - 0x80800000   (8160 kB)
      .init : 0x80b00000 - 0x80c00000   (1024 kB)
      .data : 0x80c00000 - 0x80c79014   ( 485 kB)
       .bss : 0x80c7b000 - 0x80d3da64   ( 779 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 32.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
[    0.000000] arm_arch_timer: Architected cp15 timer(s) running at 19.20MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x46d987e47, max_idle_ns: 440795202767 ns
[    0.000008] sched_clock: 56 bits at 19MHz, resolution 52ns, wraps every 4398046511078ns
[    0.000021] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 52ns
[    0.000322] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000342] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.000365] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 38.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=192000)
[    0.000381] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.000711] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000720] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.001708] Disabling cpuset control group subsystem
[    0.001873] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.001912] ftrace: allocating 22390 entries in 66 pages
[    0.054461] CPU0: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.054479] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.054555] Setting up static identity map for 0x100000 - 0x100034
[    0.056751] CPU1: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.056759] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.057478] CPU2: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.057485] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 0, mpidr 80000002
[    0.058153] CPU3: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.058160] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 0, mpidr 80000003
[    0.058243] Brought up 4 CPUs
[    0.058253] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (153.60 BogoMIPS).
[    0.058258] CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.058261] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.059056] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.070277] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 40 variant 3 rev 4
[    0.070553] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.070569] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.071106] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.071995] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.074346] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.083309] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.083315] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.083467] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.085343] bcm2835-mbox 3f00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.085862] uart-pl011 3f201000.serial: could not find pctldev for node /soc/gpio@7e200000/uart0_pins, deferring probe
[    0.155045] bcm2835-dma 3f007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager at bb80f000, dmachans=0x1
[    0.156858] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.157014] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.157089] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.157178] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.164023] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2017-07-03 14:16
[    0.165495] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.212328] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.212405] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.212597] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.212844] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.225021] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.225877] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.225984] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.226169] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.226257] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.226298] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.226505] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.226897] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.226902] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.226906] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.226910] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.227938] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.230195] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=18 bucket_order=4
[    0.246293] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    0.247263] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.247288] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.247293] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.249714] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 251)
[    0.249831] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.249836] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    0.250138] io scheduler cfq registered
[    0.255811] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA memory fa910000
[    0.255835] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA channel 0 @ bb80f000
[    0.292782] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x64
[    0.315729] bcm2835-rng 3f104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    0.315836] vc-cma: Videocore CMA driver
[    0.315842] vc-cma: vc_cma_base      = 0x00000000
[    0.315847] vc-cma: vc_cma_size      = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    0.315852] vc-cma: vc_cma_initial   = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    0.316052] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3dc00000 mem_size:0x3f000000(1008 MiB)
[    0.331505] brd: module loaded
[    0.340522] loop: module loaded
[    0.340534] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    0.341080] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    0.341096] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    0.569160] Core Release: 2.80a
[    0.569168] Setting default values for core params
[    0.569200] Finished setting default values for core params
[    0.769590] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    0.769595] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    0.769599] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    0.769605] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    0.769618] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    0.769981] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1032: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = 0xba904000 dma = 0xfa904000 len=9024
[    0.770007] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
Non-periodic Split Transactions
Periodic Split Transactions
High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
[    0.770013] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    0.770060] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:459: FIQ on core 1 at 0x8058ef90
[    0.770070] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:460: FIQ ASM at 0x8058f300 length 36
[    0.770082] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:486: MPHI regs_base at 0xbb87a000
[    0.770139] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    0.770173] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.770205] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: irq 62, io mem 0x00000000
[    0.770251] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    0.770256] Init: Power Port (0)
[    0.770454] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.770465] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.770473] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    0.770481] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.35-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    0.770489] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 3f980000.usb
[    0.771340] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.771378] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    0.772070] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    0.772075] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    0.772079] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    0.772092] Module dwc_common_port init
[    0.772315] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    0.772544] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.773546] bcm2835-wdt 3f100000.watchdog: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    0.773822] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=600000 max=1200000
[    0.774210] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.774215] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.774486] sdhost-bcm2835 3f202000.sdhost: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    0.776694] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    0.776794] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    0.779416] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    0.779606] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    0.779799] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    0.779802] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    0.780606] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xba980000, is_master = 0
[    0.782631] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    0.782654] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.782768] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    0.783253] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    0.783946] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.784297] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
[    0.784308] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    0.791441] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
[    0.797468] 3f201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 87, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    0.799126] sdhost: log_buf @ ba907000 (fa907000)
[    0.875530] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    0.877740] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    0.877747] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: DMA channel allocated
[    0.935631] of_cfs_init
[    0.935764] of_cfs_init: OK
[    0.938346] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p7...
[    0.945298] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    0.947301] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 59b4
[    0.947995] mmcblk0: mmc0:59b4 USD   14.7 GiB
[    0.952565]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 < p5 p6 p7 >
[    0.954369] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    0.955927] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    0.957474] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    0.960252] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    0.985628] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    1.052160] random: fast init done
[    1.069425] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    1.069470] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:7.
[    1.079624] devtmpfs: mounted
[    1.081632] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K (80b00000 - 80c00000)
[    1.110988] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    1.185552] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    1.185698] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[    1.413413] systemd[1]: systemd 215 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR)
[    1.413767] systemd[1]: Detected architecture 'arm'.
[    1.415879] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514
[    1.415892] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.416729] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.416822] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    1.537685] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.539108] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'ipv6'
[    1.541601] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <raspberrypi>.
[    1.541758] systemd[1]: Initializing machine ID from random generator.
[    1.541973] systemd[1]: Installed transient /etc/machine-id file.
[    1.735576] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    1.865849] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[    1.865863] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.868686] smsc95xx v1.0.5
[    1.959454] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:b7:d1:97
[    2.055566] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    2.131158] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service, ignoring: Unit regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
[    2.134848] systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    2.135195] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    2.135276] systemd[1]: Starting Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    2.187833] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
[    2.187848] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.187856] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB-Serial Controller
[    2.187863] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[    2.286529] fuse init (API version 7.26)
[    2.368269] i2c /dev entries driver
[    2.631808] systemd-udevd[144]: starting version 215
[    3.349987] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    4.245210] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[    4.245295] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[    4.245385] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[    4.248545] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[    4.248664] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[    4.248758] pl2303 1-1.3:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[    4.252749] usb 1-1.3: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    4.289651] gpiomem-bcm2835 3f200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x3f200000
[    4.640476] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    4.793900] brcmfmac: Firmware version = wl0: Aug  7 2017 00:46:29 version 7.45.41.46 (r666254 CY) FWID 01-f8a78378
[    5.545973] systemd-journald[139]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    7.434676] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    7.434686] brcmfmac: power management disabled
[    7.726822] uart-pl011 3f201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[    8.297891] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[    8.411149] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:3 across:487420k SSFS
[    8.447242] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    8.491717] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (15360 buckets, 61440 max)
[    8.695868] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   10.460514] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
[   12.289538] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   12.289625] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   12.289630] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.289656] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.289672] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.289706] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   12.302603] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   12.302616] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   12.302621] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   12.302782] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   12.555213] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   12.555220] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   12.555232] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.058664] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   61.667200] random: crng init done
[  439.641435] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_stop_ap: setting INFRA mode failed -7
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

**UPDATE 3**
I checked [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) for configuration updates as it changed in february, and I found these 2 differences:
1 ) the use of **systemctl** instead of **service** for starting **dnsmasq** and **hostapd**
2 ) the result of **sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"**
is now:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Jun  2 01:53:46 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [8:463]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:146]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [9:889]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [9:889]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun  2 01:53:46 2018
```

instead of:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Jan 25 23:41:32 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:40]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jan 25 23:41:32 2018
```

**UPDATE 4**
my kernel version as requested by @eftshift0

```
uname -a
```

Linux raspberrypi 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

**UPDATE 5**
`dpkg -l raspberrypi-kernel`:
**1.20170703-1**
`/etc/apt/sorces.list`:
**deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi**

Comment: Is there a (related) message in file /var/log/syslog? Or is there an error message if you run this command? **sudo dmesg**

Comment: I updated with result

Comment: The error that is showing up on your dmesg output is poiting to a "lower level" problem (which might have been corrected already as pointed out) so fixing it by just changing netfilter's rules makes no sense to me.... unless it's a bug on the driver that is being fired by netfilter itself... but it feels unlikely. About using service instead of systemctl, that also doesn't make sense. Bottom line: I hope I'm wrong but I'd say you just got lucky but it might break any time.

Comment: @eftshift0 it makes no sense even for me, but I didn't understand: so do you think the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using an outdated driver :-) Did you update already?

Comment: I only updated Raspbian, how can I update the driver? So the error is `brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_stop_ap: setting INFRA mode failed -7` ?

Comment: The driver is updated with the kernel so you are using the updated version. That might be why it's working fine now.

Comment: unfortunately today I'm getting again: **brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_stop_ap: setting INFRA mode failed -7** so it didn't solve my problem

Comment: What kernel version is it running? I think the standard way to find out is running **uname -a**

Comment: I wrote it on UPDATE 4

Comment: I just checked on one of my raspberries and it has 4.14.34: **Linux raspberrypi 4.14.34-v7+ #1110 SMP Mon Apr 16 15:18:51 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux**

Comment: how can this be possible after I ran **apt update && apt dist-upgrade** , should not be the latest stable?

Comment: It should.... I guess. what is the output of this? **dpkg -l raspberrypi-kernel**. Mine says it's version **1.20180417-1**

Comment: I just took the time to look at raspberry pi kernels and that message is gone from raspberry kernels very recently. It's missing on tag raspberrypi-kernel_1.20180328-1 (associated to linux 4.14.30).

Comment: Are you using raspbian stretch? That can be seen in /etc/apt/sorces.list. My config file says `deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi`

Comment: See UPDATE 5. so if not with **apt update && apt dist-upgrade** , how can I upgrade my Jessie into Stretch?

Comment: Would it be possible to use a different memory card so that you don't bust this one, just in case? Then download stretch image and install it and configure the stuff as you had before. If that's not a possibility, I'd say: make an image of your current memory card before updating in case you want to "revert" back later. And it's very simple. Edit the sources.list and change the word "jessie" for stretch. Then `apt update && apt dist-upgrade`. Cross your fingers and you should end up in stretch. That works fine on PCs but don't know if that's standard rpi procedure.

Comment: Just to make sure: Do you run `apt update && apt dist-upgrade` as root/sudoer?

Comment: This solved it for me: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58529/access-point-service-is-not-starting-on-boot-with-systemd?newreg=2546ed62d0e842d18b2e4faa97b369f3

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issue with an external WLAN Adapter directly connected to the RasPI. Problem was, that the Power used by the WLAN Adapter somtimes exceeded the RasPIs capacity. The odd thing was, that nothing about that was found in the logs. My solution to the problem was to use an active USB Hub with external Power-Supply.

Comment: for the moment I'm not using an external WLAN Adapter. I use a 5v 3A power source via GPIO, but I have the same problem using the Raspberry Pi power supply

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a updated kernel? Have you run **apt update && apt dist-upgrade**?

From what I can gather on a quick search, that part of the code from the driver with that error message has been removed. Here's the patch: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10061657/ Not completely sure it's **the** patch, but anyway.

And I just checked on kernel code and it's gone: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.14.y/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/cfg80211.c.

I'd say update and see if it gets solved.

Comment: I installed and updated Raspbian in january, I'll try `apt update && apt dist-upgrade` and I'll let you know

Comment: still same problem after **apt update && apt dist-upgrade** see UPDATE 2 for **sudo dmesg** result